# Regular heptagon with integer-coordinate vertices in three dimensions?

Tags: geometry, 3d, polygons, integer-lattices

The $d$-dimensional "integer lattice", $\mathbb{Z}^d$, is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with integer coordinates.

First of all, for $n\neq 4$, a regular $n$-gon is impossible to place so that its vertices lie in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, the integer lattice in the *plane*. But what about the 3D space?

I have examples for regular triangle, hexagon, and square, but I think for the other $n$s, it is not possible. Why? Or are there examples for regular heptagons?

Comment: Conduct a web search for "lattice polygon". For example, according to [this note](http://dynamicsofpolygons.org/PDFs/LatticePolygons.pdf), the square, equilateral triangle, and regular hexagon are the only regular polygons in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ (the integer lattice of dimension $d$) for any $d$.

Comment: Thanks, your note was helpful. Although I wish someone has a proof without trigonometry.

Comment: you might also follow the search for crystallographically allowed symmetries (resp. conversely: forbidden symmetries). - In fact, the appearance of disallowed symmetries like fivefold, eightfold, twelvefold, and icosahedral ones within Bragg reflections of metal alloys since the eighties lead to the theme of quasicrystals, i.e. non-periodic but still quasiperiodic structures.